# How can i use new line in jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Example:

```
$("#sample_id").val("This is sample String 
This new line for testing");
```

Actually this script is not working. How to use multiple lines in single jquery?

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Add "\n" wherever you need to start new line

Comment: or <br> if it's not a textarea or alertbox

Comment: That's not valid JS, as you know. You need to explain what you are trying to achieve, currently the question is unclear. You cant just make invalid code valid, which is what your current question suggests you want

Comment: You didn't explain what is the element with this id "sample_id" , as .val() is not working for div and span, .val() can be used with inputs, but if it is a div you can use .text()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this will work

```
$("#sample_id").val("This is sample String \
                     This new line for testing");
```

If multiple lines in jquery use `\` to separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

Should do

```
$("#sample_id").val("This is sample String \nThis new line for testing");
```

or

```
var x = `This is sample String 
This new line for testing`;

$("#sample_id").val(x);
```

Notice ``` Symblol `` ``` Grave Accent is not `''`

If you want to set it

```
var textareavalue = $("#sample_id").val();
textareavalue = textareavalue.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

Now this variable has `<br>` instead of `\n`

Comment: Not working @void. When i am trying to use multiple lines jquery is not accepting.

Comment: Be aware template strings (enclosed by `) are ES6 and are not currently supported in IE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: @DineshG you trying to enter it in `textarea` or `input type=text`

Comment: i am getting the value from textarea and assign to jquery variblae

Comment: @DineshG But then that's completly different behaviour than what suggests your question. In your question, you are trying to set it, not getting it. Provide relevant sample in question itself

Comment: @void Good one but i cannot upvote your answer more than once, unfortunately... ;)